# AWS SAM: How do you manage a GraphQL AppSync schema update?

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I use AWS SAM on an app, and I'd like to use AppSync with it.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  poc
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  Env:
      Type: String
Resources:
  Api:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "poc-${Env}"
      AuthenticationType: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: !Ref AuthUserPool
        AwsRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
        DefaultAction: "ALLOW"
  Schema:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema
    Properties:
      ApiId: !GetAtt Api.ApiId
      DefinitionS3Location: ./schema.graphql
```

This config works well at creation time.
But if I update my GraphQL schema file (schema.graphql) and run `sam deploy`, it is not updated probably because no attribute changes from the CloudFormation point of view.

How would you properly make sure the schema is updated ?

Answer (score 2):

My bad, I was using SAM as if it was Amplify

If you run `sam build` before `sam deploy` - the new Schema is well deployed

Comment: You made my day!